# Return type for DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler?

Tags: c#

being the C# newbie that I undoubtedly am, I'm a bit confused that you cannot set a return type on the DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler when using WebClient and the DownloadStringAsync method. Say I wanted to write some generic methods to return the HTML content of any web page, how would I go about returning the string if you cannot set a return type. I feel i'm missing something obvious here, any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that you're *called back* by the `WebClient` when the data is ready - when you subscribe to the event, you're basically saying "call this when you've finished". When you return from the callback, you're not returning to *your* code, you're returning back to `WebClient`. Why would it want to know the string, when it's just given it to you? :)

No, the idea is that your callback does what it needs to with the data (in the [`Result`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.downloadstringcompletedeventargs.result.aspx) property of the event argument). That might mean stashing it somewhere, or writing it to the file system - whatever you need to do.

Don't worry - thinking asynchronously is tricky. You'll get there though :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't set a return type because this is using the standard even handler pattern for callbacks (i.e. and `Object` sender and `EventArgs` for arguments)

The content of the page will be encapsulated in the [`DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.downloadstringcompletedeventargs.aspx) which get passed to the callback method (more specifically `DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs.Result` contains the downloaded data).

Answer (score 0):

[DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.downloadstringcompletedeventargs.aspx)  is an event handler. In other words, it is a method that the class calls when it is finished downloading the string from the source.  The results of the event are contained within the parameters.  so, you attach to the event and then in your method, you use the parameters however you want to.

hope this helps.